# How to download file in server?

Tags: file, vaadin

I want to download some text file from server, and I found component 'FileDownloader' in Vaadin.

However, I cannot find some examples. All examples are using outputStream.

Answer (score 1):

[`FileDownloader`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.4.4/com/vaadin/server/FileDownloader.html#FileDownloader%28com.vaadin.server.Resource%29) takes a `Resource` and there is a subclass [`FileResource`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.4.4/com/vaadin/server/FileResource.html) for your case (from the docs):

> FileResources are files or directories on local filesystem. The files and directories are served through URI:s to the client terminal and thus must be registered to an URI context before they can be used. The resource is automatically registered to the application when it is created

Answer (score 0):

First of all a FileDownloader needs a FileResource, so you should do something like

```
FileResource fr = new FileResource(new File("path/to/your/file/on/server"));
FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(fr);
```

After that you have to associate the FileDownload to a component, like, for example, a button

```
Button buttonDownload = new Button("Download", FontAwesome.DOWNLOAD);
fileDownloader.extend(buttonDownload);
```

This basically adds to the component an extension, which is, to keep it simple, a component-independent entity that enables easy comunication between client and server.
When you'll click the button, the extension will activate and will start the download.

Tweak the example to your needs. Cheers.